# Microsoft wild cards - find words with different endings but next to each other

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, find-and-replace, wildcards

#### Aim

Hi folks, I am building an **Index** and I am trying to search for two-word phrases but with declinations in MS Word. So what I want to find is two words next to each other with fixed beginnings but both with flexible endings (of various lengths).

So, *the following should be a match* (made-up examples, I use the Slovak language)
"didactic procedure", "didactical proceedings", "didactatical procedures".

This *should **not** be a match*, e.g. I want a match only when words are next to each other with nothing but space(s) between them:
"didactical language procedure"

#### Approach so far

I am trying to achieve my goal with Advanced Search and Wildcards, but any approach is welcomed as long as it achieves the goal.

> didact* proce*

This sort of works, but finds also the two words within any distance from each other and selects all the text between, so it is totally unusable.

> <(didact) <(price)

> <(didact)^32<(price)

> <(didact)[ ]<(price)

This would work according to the rules, but whatever I put between the words indicating one space, I always get **zero matches,** nothing is found.

#### Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following search criteria

```
<didact[a-z]{1,} <proce[a-z]{1,}
```

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for the suggestion, however the said string returns an error:

"The Find What text contains a Pattern Match expression which is not valid."

This might be because Microsoft Word has implemented Regex in its own, "unique" way.

Comment: That's odd, it worked fine for me. Do you have a space between the first and second parts?

Comment: If I don't use the Use wildcards option, it does not throw an error, but also does not find anything.
If I switch it on, it is an error. 
Screenshots:
https://www.screenpresso.com/=xHiOb

Comment: Did you copy/paste from my answer? If you did, when you pasted, did you paste text only? I'm wondering if a stray HTML character was picked up. You could also try typing in the string directly.

Comment: Hi, yes, copied - and pasted as text only. Also, checked in plaintext editor. Word does not like commas in the statement. With them removed the string is valid, but does not return any results (not found...) Thanks for keeping looking into it!

Comment: The difference between our systems must be the issue. I am running Microsoft 365 for Business and my language is US English. Regarding the commas in {1,} that's telling it there have to be at least 1 of the preceding characters, which would be [a-z]

Comment: I am using Microsoft Office 365 for Enterprise, US English for Office and Windows, but the regional setting was set to Slovakia. I have changed the regional setting to English and now it works... Thanks for the help! In my regional setting I have to use semicolon instead of comma... go figure.